# Парсинг таблицы

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

Здраствуйте. Есть парсер на phpQuery

```
$link = 'mysite.com';
$href_1 = curl($link);
$result = phpQuery::newDocument($href_1);
$table = $result->find('table')->eq(1)->find('tbody')->find('tr');

foreach ($table as $items) {
    $items = pq($items);

    $traider = $items->find('td')->eq(0)->text();
    $region = $items->find('td')->eq(1)->text();
    $base = $items->find('td')->eq(2)->text();
    $name = $items->find('td')->eq(3)->text();
    $price = $items->find('td')->eq(4)->text();
    $date = $items->find('td')->eq(5)->text();
}
```

Если искать просто таблицу -

```
$table = $result->find('table')->eq(1)
```

то все хорошо, результат ее возвращает(в чистом виде,без скриптов и т.д). Если же добавить `->find('tr')` в конце, то выдает

> Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in.

В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: Неужели никто с подобным не сталкивался?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать:

```
$table = $result->find('table')->eq(1)->find('tbody tr');
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.